# string subscript out of range - string bubble sort

Tags: c++, arrays, bubble-sort

First post here but I've been digging around for a solution to this bug.
I am getting an error "string subscript out of range"

PhoneBook is an array of class Contact object pointers.

```
static const int maxSize = 10;
Contact* phoneBook[maxSize]; //array of contact pointers
```

where Contact is defined as

```
class Contact
{
public:
    Contact();

    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    std::string name; //lName + fName
    std::string phoneNumber;
    std::string address;
};
```

Here is my bubble sort function.

```
void AddressBook::bubbleSort(Contact phoneBook[], int length)
{
Contact temp; 

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)//for n-1 passes
{
    for (int j = 0; j < length - 1; j++)
    {
        if (phoneBook->name[j] > phoneBook->name[j + 1])
        {
            temp = phoneBook[j];
            phoneBook[j] = phoneBook[j + 1];
            phoneBook[j + 1] = temp;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

here is addContact

```
void AddressBook::addContact(std::string fName, std::string lName, std::string pNumber, std::string addr) 
{
    if (isFull())
    {
        std::cout << "Is full" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    Contact *contact = new Contact;

    contact->firstName = fName;
    contact->lastName = lName;
    contact->name = lName + ", " + fName;
    contact->phoneNumber = pNumber;
    contact->address = addr;

    std::cout << contact->name + " has been added!" << std::endl;
    phoneBook[length] = contact;
    length++; 

    bubbleSort(phoneBook[maxSize], length);

}
```

and lastly, where i use it (source.cpp)

```
switch (choice) 
{
case 1:
    addrBook.addContact("Ty", "Le", "6191231234", "1234 State Street");
    addrBook.addContact("Zak", "Zachary", "6191231234", "1234 Avenue Drive");
```

I know for a fact that the problem originates from the bubbleSort function because it'll work fine when I comment it out of addContact().

Here's a picture of my error 
[(too long to copy and paste)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMfj6.jpg)

**FULL CODE**

.h
https://pastebin.com/TrtQW8Tc

.cpp
https://pastebin.com/EaGBUe9e

source
https://pastebin.com/1BR5pXZE

Answer (score 1):

This is almost a typo. Instead of indexing the `name` string in

```
    if (phoneBook->name[j] > phoneBook->name[j + 1])
```

you want to index `phonebook`

```
    if (phoneBook[j].name > phoneBook[j + 1].name)
```

Comment: Shoot.. so close. Thanks! I do get another error though, this time,                      Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
_Right_data was 0xCCCCCD04. (Error and bubbleSort updated in post)

Comment: @TylerLe 0xCCCCCD04 looks a lot like uninitialized memory (see [Wikipedia's list of common debugging codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values)) plus an offset of a member variable in a structure. Odds are you ran off the end of the stack somewhere and tried to access a pointer.

Comment: I just looked at your edit to the question and I'm going to roll it back in a few seconds. It is bad form to change a question in such a way that it renders existing answers invalid. When one solution exposes a new problem, you are better off debugging a while to see if you can solve it, and asking a new question if you cannot.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I didn't know.

Comment: No worries. Got distracted before I could finish my thought. Your new error crashes the program somewhere inside `std::string`. The odds of the error being in `std::string` are pretty close to zero due to the sheer number of people using it every day without a problem. If you look down at the bottom of Visual Studio, you'll find a Call Stack tab. Click that and you'll see how the program got to the crash site. Work your way back until you find where the 0xCCCCCCCC came from. Then you may have to do a bit more work to find out how it got there. Probably be an out-of-bounds array access.

Comment: so apparently it comes from:                                                                                         `if (phoneBook[j].name > phoneBook[j + 1].name) `                                                                    when i run                                                                    
`addrBook.addContact("Zak", "Zachary", "6191231234", "1234 Avenue Drive");`               the first time around, it runs just fine, and then the second time around, it crashes. I'm still trying to figure out as to why.